# Symfony : How to update bootstrap progress bar in array

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, symfony

I have a problem and I'm stuck with it.
I have a command which send lots of emails (with cron, it can be 300 or more emails) every 5 minutes in order to send a newsletter.

I need to know how many emails have been sent by the command and to display that result in a progress bar. All the emails are first stacked in a database, then they're deleted when sent.

My issue is to have the information of the good newsletter in my array in the progress bar (for the moment, I only have the result of the last one in all the progress bars)

My html array :

```
<table class="table table-hover mb-0">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>ID</th>
                            <th>Titre</th>
                            <th>Date de creation</th>
                            <th>Date d'envoi</th>
                            <th class="text-center">Progression envoi</th>
                            <th class='text-center'>Actions</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        {% for newsletter in newsletters %}
                            <tr>
                                <td>{{ newsletter.id }}</td>
                                <td class="align-middle">{{ newsletter.titre }}</td>
                                <td class="align-middle">
                                    {% if newsletter.dateCreation %}
                                        {{ newsletter.dateCreation|date('d/m/Y H:i') }}
                                    {% endif %}
                                </td>
                                <td class="align-middle">
                                    {% if newsletter.dateEnvoi %}
                                        {{ newsletter.dateEnvoi|date('d/m/Y H:i') }}
                                    {% endif %}
                                </td>
                                <td class="align-middle">
                                    <div class="progress">
                                        {{ include('/transmission_elu/newsletter/progressionBar.html.twig') }}
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                                <td class='text-center'>
                                    <a href="{{ path('newsletter_show', { 'id': newsletter.id, 'id_instance' : id_instance.id }) }}" class='btn btn-sm btn-outline-dark'>
                                        <i class="fas fa-eye"></i>
                                        Voir</a>
                                    <a href="{{ path('newsletter_send_confirmation', { 'id': newsletter.id, 'id_instance' : id_instance.id }) }}" class='btn btn-sm btn-outline-dark'>
                                        <i class="fas fa-paper-plane"></i>
                                        Envoyer</a>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </tbody>
                </table>
```

The progress bar html :

```
{% block body %}
    {% if nombre_emails_envoyes is defined and ratio_emails_envoyes is defined %}
        <div class="progress-bar bg-success emails-progression" id="{{ newsletter.id }}" data-id-newsletter="{{ newsletter.id }}"
             data-total-emails="{{ newsletter.totalEmails }}" role="progressbar" style="width: {{ ratio_emails_envoyes }}%" aria-valuenow="{{ ratio_emails_envoyes }}"
             aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">
            {{ nombre_emails_envoyes }}/{{ newsletter.totalEmails }} {{ newsletter.id }}
        </div>
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

My First route Controller :

```
/**
     * Lists all newsletter entities.
     *
     * @Route("/{id_liste}", name="newsletter_index", requirements={"id_liste"="\d+"}, methods={"GET"})
     *
     */
    public function indexAction($id_liste = NULL, Instance $id_instance, Request $request)
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        
        $listes = $em->getRepository(Liste::class)->findBy(['instance' => $id_instance, 'statusListe' => true]);

                if (isset($id_liste)) {
            $newsletters = $em->getRepository(Newsletter::class)->findBy(['newslettersListe' => $id_liste], ['id' => 'DESC']);
            $newsletters_total = $em->getRepository(Newsletter::class)->findBy(['newslettersListe' => $id_liste]);
        } else {
            $newsletters = $em->getRepository(Newsletter::class)->findBy(['instance' => $id_instance], ['id' => 'DESC']);
            $newsletters_total = $em->getRepository(Newsletter::class)->findBy(['instance' => $id_instance]);
        }

        $nombreEmailsEnvoyes = 0;
        $ratioEmailsEnvoyes = 0;

        return $this->render('transmission_elu/newsletter/index.html.twig', array(
            'newsletters' => $newsletters,
            'id_instance' => $id_instance,
            'listes' => $listes,
            'id_liste' => $id_liste,
            'nombre_emails_envoyes' => $nombreEmailsEnvoyes,
            'ratio_emails_envoyes' => $ratioEmailsEnvoyes,
        ));
    }
```

I use a script to get the newsletter's informations and send them to my controller in an other route :
script:

```
var newsletterIdsList = [];

jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    var progressBar = document.querySelectorAll('.progress > div')
    progressBar.forEach(function (bar){
        var getIdNewsletter = parseInt(bar.dataset.idNewsletter);
        var getIdListOfNewsletter = parseInt(bar.dataset.idListe);
        var getNombreTotalEmails = parseInt(bar.dataset.totalEmails)
        newsletterIdsList.push({
            newsletter: getIdNewsletter,
            liste: getIdListOfNewsletter,
            totalEmails: getNombreTotalEmails
        });
    })
    setTimeout(fetchTotalEmails, 1000);
    setInterval(fetchTotalEmails, 5000);
})

function fetchTotalEmails()
{
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: urlEmailNewsletter,
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            'newsletterInformations': newsletterIdsList,
        },
        success: function (data) {
            if (!data.error === false) {
                return null;
            } else {
                var progressionBar = jQuery('.progress');
                progressionBar.html(data);
            }
        }
    })
}
```

Second route in Controller :

```
/**
     * @Route("/emails/{id}", name="emails_newsletter", methods={"GET", "POST"})
     */
    public function emailNewsletter(Request $request, NewsletterRepository $newsletterRepository, $id, EmailRepository $emailRepository)
    {
        //Récupération des informations de la newsletter (id newsletter, id liste et id instance)
        $newslettersInformations = $request->request->get('newsletterInformations');
        foreach ($newslettersInformations as $information) {
            $idNewsletter = $information['newsletter'];
            $idListe = $information['liste'];

            $newsletter = $newsletterRepository->find($idNewsletter);
            if (isset($idListe)) {
                $newsletters = $newsletterRepository->findBy(['newslettersListe' => $idListe], ['id' => 'DESC']);
            }
    //        else {
    //            $newsletters = $em->getRepository(Newsletter::class)->findBy(['instance' => $id_instance], ['id' => 'DESC'], $demande_par_page, $demande_index);
    //            $newsletters_total = $em->getRepository(Newsletter::class)->findBy(['instance' => $id_instance]);

            $nombreEmailsrestantsBDD = $emailRepository->countTotalEmailsToSend($idNewsletter);
            $totalAEnvoyer = $information['totalEmails'];
            $nombreEmailsEnvoyes = $totalAEnvoyer - $nombreEmailsrestantsBDD;
            $ratioEmailsEnvoyes = null;
            //Calcul du pourcentage d'envoi effectué pour affichage barre progression
            if ($totalAEnvoyer === 0) {
                $ratioEmailsEnvoyes = 0;
            } else {
                $ratioEmailsEnvoyes = (int)$nombreEmailsEnvoyes/(int)$totalAEnvoyer*100;
            }

            return $this->render('transmission_elu/newsletter/progressionBar.html.twig', array(
                'newsletter' => $newsletter,
                'ratio_emails_envoyes' => $ratioEmailsEnvoyes,
                'nombre_emails_envoyes' => $nombreEmailsEnvoyes,
                'id_liste' => $idListe
            ));
        }
        return ;
    }
```

Thanks a lot for any help

Comment: For symfony 5 and up I would suggest to use UX controllers. There will be a separate timer instance for every element if you want it each will be controlled by a separate controller.
For Symfony 4 I would suggest to implement the separate controllers yourself and give every newsletter bar an id (loop index or php controller array index)

Comment: I'm in Symfony 4.4. I've created an id for the progress-bar (code added, I forgot to put it in my post), but I don't succeed to loop over it. I must be wrong somewhere in a loop, but I don't find where....

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I've made the all thing totally differently.

In the first controller, I just pushed the total of emails in the database (in an other entity).
With the other Controller, in its view, I just called the items of the entity.
I've put all the logic of getting the new number of emails in this other controller, with a send to the database until job is done.

In the same time, the client just said that the progress bar wasn't necessary, so, just two numbers to give...